# To display loader image while loading the next page in phonegap android application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a phonegap android application which consists of three html pages.Each page have some dynamic data that loads on page initialization. I want to display a loader image on the click of a button to navigate to other html page while loading it.

How can i implement this? Is there any default function for this ?

Comment: Phonegap doesnt handle the navigation between pages. You need to use jQuery mobile or a similar framework.

Comment: i am using jquery mobile bt don't know the way to implement it.Any Help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation found [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/).

```
function showSpinner(){
    $.mobile.loading("show");
}

function hideSpinner(){
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is also good there is another option manually you have to create one div on each HTML page like

```
 <div id="pageLoader">
    <div>
       <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> // give here path of any loader image you want
    </div>
 </div>
```

then call  $("#pageLoader").show()  and   $("#pageLoader").hide()  wherever you want to show and hide loading.

Answer (score 0):

for android use

```
 navigator.notification.activityStart
```

for detail check this

[show-loading-screen-in-phonegap-app](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/show-loading-screen-in-phonegap-app.html)